# What would you call this type of solution set?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

In Linear Algebra, I am often asked to find the solution set to some linear system. There are different ways to represent these solutions.

For example you could write it as 
1 . a system of equations: $x_{1} + 2x_{2} + 3x_{3} = 0$ 
2. a spanning set (of vectors): $span
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
-3 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}
$

3. a solution set in parametric or vector form (similar to span):
$ 
x_{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+ x_{3}
\begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$

(feel free to correct the terms in the examples above as well. I know what they look like just not what to call them.)

How would you describe the following representation of a solution set with the proper mathematical terminology?

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\left\{
 \left(
  \begin{array} {c}
  -(2x_{2}+3x_{3}) \\
  x_{2} \\
  x_{3}
  \end{array}
 \right) 
%
  \begin{array} {|c}
  \\ \\ \\
  \end{array}
%
  \begin{array} {c}
  x_{2}, x_{3} \in \mathbb{R}
  \end{array} 
\right\}
$$

Comment: This is what is called parametric.

Answer (score 0):

As Arnaud Mortier pointed out in a comment, that's still writing the solution in "parametric" form. But you're now using "[set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation)" to represent the solution set.